# log files with .log extension is getting downloaded instead of opening in the browser with nginx server

Tags: server, nginx

I have created a web server using nginx and using it to store log files. When I access any of the .log file, it downloads the file instead of opening it in the browser.

is there any special setting to get the log file open in the browser instead of downloading ?

Comment: On the download bar, click the link next to the downloaded file and choose "Always open files of this type" if you run Google Chrome. Other browsers may have similar options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust NGINX configuration and specify the one MIME type that will cause the browser to display `.log` files, that is `text/plain` in this case:

Open `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and add the `types` directive:

```
http {
...
    types {
        text/plain log;
    }
...
}
```

Then reload NGINX configuration by running:

```
service nginx reload
```